# Similarweb shows a impossibly very low group share while comparing sites

Tags: seo, seo-competition-analysis

We use similarweb for keyword analysis vs competition.
Tool Url : https://www.similarweb.com/

But it shows a metric : **Total Group Traffic Share** and indicates that it is :

***Percent of search traffic sent by this keyword to the group of websites selected***

Use Case :

Sites Selected : examplea.com,exampleb.com .... on keywords keyword1, keyword2..

But even for branded keyword examplea that match exactly with the examplea site under consideration, the group share was shown as 10% (though it takes 100% of the share group get, which is fine)

So where is 90% traffic going in case of the branded keyword examplea, and due to this we are losing reliability on this data.

[image]

Can someone explain ?

Comment: I hate tools like this. This means nothing. You also have no idea if it's even accurate.

Comment: @JohnConde I hate tools like this too. Most of them cannot possibly be accurate. ;-) It is just not statistically possible.